# jQuery: If condition inside scroll event not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a pinned widget at the bottom of the window (fixed positioned) which should show/hide based on the position of the widget with respect to the content beneath the widget on the page. If user scroll pass ahead of the `.page-isi` content then the `.pinned-isi` should hide otherwise show. When I did console log, the condition is triggering correctly however after attaching show/hide function to `$('.pinned-isi')`, it toggle repeatedly back and forth with scroll instead of just triggering the hide function as expected.

```
$('.full-wrapper').scroll(function(){
    if ($('.page-isi').offset().top - 50 >= $('.pinned-isi').offset().top){
        $('.pinned-isi').show();
    } else {
        $('.pinned-isi').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you share executable demo/snippet or [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because when you do `$('.pinned-isi').hide();` next time `$('.pinned-isi').offset().top` will be 0.

Better save your element offset before you hide it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var pinnTop = $('.pinned-isi').offset().top;
  $('.full-wrapper').scroll(function() {
    if ((-1 * $('.page-isi').offset().top - 50) >= pinnTop) {
      $('.pinned-isi').show();
    } else {
      $('.pinned-isi').hide();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.full-wrapper {
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: auto;
}
.page-isi {
  height: 3000px;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(90deg, #00cb4c 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 90deg, color-stop(0%, #00cb4c), color-stop(100%, #ffffff));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg, #00cb4c 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(90deg, #00cb4c 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(90deg, #00cb4c 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#00cb4c', endColorstr='#ffffff', GradientType='0');
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #00cb4c 0%, #ffffff 100%);
  position: relative;
}
.pinned-isi {
  height: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="full-wrapper">
  <div class="page-isi">
    <div class="pinned-isi">
      PINNED
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 7 Seconds faster and even with an example :D +1

Answer (score 1):

That's because the `offset` of `.pinned-isi` is affected due the *toggleing*. You could try to cache the offset outside of your `scroll`-handler.

```
var fixedPoint = $('.pinned-isi').offset().top

$(window).resize(function(){
    fixedPoint = $('.pinned-isi').offset().top
});

$('.full-wrapper').scroll(function(){
    if ($('.page-isi').offset().top - 50 >= fixedPoint){
        $('.pinned-isi').show();
    } else {
        $('.pinned-isi').hide();
    }
});
```

Also, as I can see you just compare the elements offsets and don't *include* the scroll position... However, it's hard to give a correct answer, without your markup.